# toBlocking() is marked unstable with @Beta

Tags: rx-java

I am trying to get the value from a Single object in RxJava using toBlocking().value(). It works fine but sonarLint is giving me the suggestion that toBlocking() is marked unstable with @Beta. what is the best approach to get the value from Single?

```
Single<Car> carSingle = getCar();
System.out.println(carSingle.toBlocking().value().getModel());
```